# With the Linux "cat" command, how do I show only certain lines by number

Tags: text-processing, cat

If I use `cat -n text.txt` to automatically number the lines, how do I then use the command to show only certain numbered lines.

Comment: What do you mean with "show only certain numbered lines", can you put an expected output?

Comment: There's probably going to be a million ways to do this. `tail` + `head` can also do this, as can `awk`

Comment: Note to self: create a python script for this and release it to the public :)

Answer (score 309):

Use `sed`

Usage

```
$ cat file
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
```

To print one line (5)

```
$ sed -n 5p file
Line 5
```

To print multiple lines (5 & 8)

```
$ sed -n -e 5p -e 8p file
Line 5
Line 8
```

To print specific range (5 - 8)

```
$ sed -n 5,8p file
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
```

To print range with other specific line (5 - 8 & 10)

```
$ sed -n -e 5,8p -e 10p file
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 10
```

Comment: Note that for a range including the first line (for example first 5 lines), you'll use `sed -n 1,5p ...` not `sed -n 0,5p ...`. At least for the version of `sed` installed by default on Mac OS 10.15.

Answer (score 56):

One way of doing it is by using `sed`:

```bash
cat -n text.txt | sed '11d'
```

where 11 is the number of the line you want removed.

Or to remove all but 11:

```bash
cat -n text.txt | sed '11!d'
```

Ranges are also possible:

```bash
cat -n text.txt | sed '9,12!d'
```

And `cat -n` isn't even needed:

```bash
sed '9,12!d' text.txt
```

Comment: Yes, `cat -n` isn't needed, but you are gonna have it without line numbers.

Answer (score 46):

You can use awk straight up.

```
awk 'NR==1' file.txt
```

replacing '1' with the desired line number.

Comment: This is by a million miles the best answer here and deserves a lot more love than it has.

Comment: Simple solution for 50ish years. Good post.

Comment: I concur that this is the very best answer. To add on top you can use equivalence operators to filter data out ie. `awk 'NR>=20' file.txt`

Answer (score 22):

Depending on goals I like head or grep

`cat /var/log/syslog -n | head -n 50 | tail -n 10`

will return lines 41 thru 50.

or

`cat /var/log/syslog -n | grep " 50" -b10 -a10`

will show lines 40 thru 60. The problem with the grep method is that you have to use account for padding of  the line numbers (notice the space)

Both are quite handy for parsing log files.

Comment: Neither example needs `cat` though

Comment: well yeah... but.... but...   .....   There are better ways. The question asked about using cat though, so I used it.

Comment: `cat` can't do what the OP wants

Comment: Nice tricks. Tx.

Comment: loved the grep "foo" -b10 -a10 ! Very useful

Answer (score 5):

As others have shown you, there is no need to use `cat -n`. Other programs will do it for you. If, however, you really need to parse the output of `cat -n` and show only specific lines (for example, 4-8, 12 and 42), you could do:

```
$ cat -n file | awk '$1>=4 && $1<=8 || $1==12 || $1==42'
 4  Line 4
 5  Line 5
 6  Line 6
 7  Line 7
 8  Line 8
12  Line 12
42  Line 42
```

In `awk`, `$1` is the first field, so this command prints all lines whose first fields are i) between 4 and 8 (inclusive) or ii) 12 or iii) 42.

If you also want to remove the field added by `cat -n` to get the original lines from the file, you can do:

```
$ cat -n file | awk '$1>=4 && $1<=8 || $1==12 || $1==42{sub(/^\s*[0-9]+\s*/,""); print}'
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 12
Line 42
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `NR` instead of `$1`?

Comment: @SolomonUcko sure, but since I was demonstrating how to do this using `cat -n` specifically, I thought I would use the output that `cat -n` provides.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed to show only one number and loop this with a for loop:

```
for line in 1 3 7 11; do sed -n ${line}p text.txt; done
```