# Modifying cat command to number paragraphs and display last paragraph only

Tags: cat, text

I have a text file for which I need to do three things:

1. Modify the "cat" command to highlight keywords whilst showing the complete contents of the file. [SOLUTION FOUND](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106565/how-to-highlight-a-word-in-the-output-of-cat)
2. Modify the "cat" command to automatically number the paragraphs. These are separated by a single blank line.
3. Modify the "cat" command to display the final paragraph only.

The tricky part is that all of these need to be done by **modifying the cat** command.

I've seen many forum posts explaining that cat is not meant for this - and I can entirely see why. However, the challenge is that I **have to use cat**!

Comment: Two questions: Is this homework? Have you read the `cat` manual?

Comment: Not homework. More like a project. I've not read it cover-to-cover, but the stuff I've looked at was either too complex for me or doesn't look possible.

Comment: Your [SOLUTION FOUND](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106565/how-to-highlight-a-word-in-the-output-of-cat) only "uses `cat`" in the sense that it (superfluously) uses `cat` to provide input to `grep`. If that's all that you need to complete the "challenge" then for parts (2) and (3) you can just use *any* commands that accept standard input

Comment: `cat` is completely irrelevant for this problem. Why on earth would you insist on using it? Even as a homework assignment it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @steeldriver - I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: @Giles Believe me, I know! I'm just stuck with the remit of the assignment. It's not a homework; I'm a teacher and this is an assignment set for my students by the exam board. They are very clear that you have to modify cat to achieve these aims.

Comment: [Your classmate has asked this on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/822527/number-paragraphs-with-cat-command). It doesn't make any more sense the second time. (Unless you mean to **modify** cat rather than **use** cat? i.e. is this a C programming exercise rather than a shell exercise?)

Comment: @Gilles still not a student, but thanks nevertheless. I missed that post. The question does refer to 'modify' but I cannot imagine that they intend for us to C programming.

Comment: @ifellover well, that's the only way you can possibly "modify" cat. Sorry if the reception here has been less than positive but, frankly, we're tired of people asking this same question. It didn't make any sense the first time it was asked and hasn't improved by repetition. If this is something forced on you by someone else, you need to let them know that they don't know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use cat?

```
cat -n  thefile | tail -n1
```

What do you mean with "Highlight keywords whilst showing the complete contents of the file."

What keywords you want to highlight?

What is the purpose to number all the paragraphs but to show only the last one?  (NOTE: the command that i write will do exactly this, cat -n to number the paragraphs, and tail -n1 to show only the last paragraph.)

Comment: Thank you - that actually solves 2 and 3 nicely.   As for highlighting - sorry I should be more specific. I need to be able to highlight a particular word whenever it occurs within the text. So for example, in the sentence 'This is my paragraph', I may want to highlight (add colour) to the word 'paragraph'.

Comment: I'm afraid I absolutely have to use cat. I know there are, and have found, far better solutions without it.

Comment: @ifellover just a note: the above numbers and/or selects *lines* - not "paragraphs" that are "separated by a single blank line"

Comment: cat -n  thefile | tail -n1  | grep --color "paragraph" ... See if that help...

Comment: Also `-n` will also number the empty lines `-b` will number non-empty lines.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the note. For now, I'm going to assume that the ambiguity within the question allows one paragraph per line. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with teaching gcse computing coursework ;) It doesn't specify to use cat in the question, at least in the one on the question sheet!

I just did

```
perl -00pe ‘s/^/$. /’ textfile
```

for 7ii
and

```
perl -00pe ‘s/^/$. /’ jamestextfile | tail -n1
```

for 7iii

The important thing in question 7 is using pipe and stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure I entirely agree with your interpretation of the question - you may want to check again. But my question was not for the controlled assessment task; I'm not a teacher who provides his students with solutions to these problems. I posted only to clarify my own subject knowledge.

As for being _your_ teacher, it's highly unlikely. But if you were my student, I would commend you for your contribution to this thread and recognise your potential as a Computer Scientist. I like to learn just as much from my students as they learn from me. Keep going!

Comment: Right @james.edwardsiscoolatschool, the intension of the quesitons seems to be more using pipe than [Use Of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat)) only.

Answer (score 0):

I found the question and the comments interesting, so I had a deeper look into it. According the comments given I understand that the question is more about "*How to **modify the output** of the cat command?*", maybe just by using command switches and if possible. Just a note, the question would be easier to understand if a sample input is given and the expected output is shown.

It is assumed the following `TEST_FILE` is given:

```
This is the first (1) paragraph. This is the second (2) sentence. This is the third (3) sentence.\n The fourth (4) sentence of the first (1) paragraph is the second (2) line of the first (1) paragraph.

This is the second (2) paragraph. This is the second (2) sentence of the second (2) paragraph. This is the third (3) sentence of the second (2) paragraph.


This is the third (3) paragraph. This is the second (2) sentence. This is the third (3) sentence of the second (3) paragraph.



This is the fourth (4) paragraph. This is the second (2) sentence of the fourth (4) paragraph. This is the third (3) sentence.




This is the fifth (5) paragraph. This is the second (2) sentence. This is the third (3) sentence.\n The fourth (4) sentence of the fifth (5) paragraph is the second (2) line of the fifth (5) paragraph.
```

The paragraphs are not separated by a single blank line (as it was requested), but it is good to learn how some of the commands are working.

**Suppress repeated empty output lines**:

```
cat -s TEST_FILE 
This is the first (1) paragraph. ...

This is the second (2) paragraph. ...

This is the third (3) paragraph. ...

This is the fourth (4) paragraph. ...

This is the fifth (5) paragraph. ...
```

**Additionally number all output lines**:

```
cat -s -n TEST_FILE
     1 This is the first (1) paragraph. ...
     2
     3 This is the second (2) paragraph. ...
     4
     5 This is the third (3) paragraph. ...
     6
     7 This is the fourth (4) paragraph. ...
     8
     9 This is the fifth (5) paragraph. ...
```

**And number nonempty output lines only**:

```
cat -s -n -b TEST_FILE
     1 This is the first (1) paragraph. ...

     2 This is the second (2) paragraph. ...

     3 This is the third (3) paragraph. ...

     4 This is the fourth (4) paragraph. ...

     5 This is the fifth (5) paragraph. ...
```

According your "SOLUTION FOUND" it seems to be agreed to use pipe and a second command to modify the output of the `cat` command. At least for your third requirement it would be necessary.

Therefore you could achieve the same result with number lines `nl` (but only if the the empty lines are really empty and do not contain white spaces):

```
cat TEST_FILE | nl
     1  This is the first (1) paragraph. ...

     2  This is the second (2) paragraph. ...


     3  This is the third (3) paragraph. ...



     4  This is the fourth (4) paragraph. ...




     5  This is the fifth (5) paragraph. ...
```

It would then be possible to [Remove blank lines with `grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493076/6771046) also:

```
cat -s -n -b TEST_FILE | grep .
```

In case of lines with whitespaces it would be necessary to remove them first:

```
grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' TEST_FILE | nl
```

To [Echo newline in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467448/6771046) you can use:

```
echo -e $(cat -s TEST_FILE | tail -1)
echo -e $(cat -s -n -b TEST_FILE | tail -1)
```

You could also [show certain lines numbers only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288523/266568). But this is already leaving the scope of the question.